# How do I check if a string has at least one number in it using Ruby?

Tags: ruby, regex, string, numbers

I need to check to see if a string contains at least one number in it using Ruby (and I assume some sort of regex?).

How would I do that?

Comment: http://public.kvalley.com/regex/regex.asp

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can use the `String` class's `=~` method with the regex `/\d/` as the argument.

Here's an example:

```
s = 'abc123'

if s =~ /\d/         # Calling String's =~ method.
  puts "The String #{s} has a number in it."
else
  puts "The String #{s} does not have a number in it."
end
```

Answer (score 13):

Alternatively, without using a regex:

```
def has_digits?(str)
  str.count("0-9") > 0
end
```

Comment: that's probably less efficient, if you ignore the overhead of compiling the regular expression (which is fair if the test is being done in a large loop or the string to check is very long). For a degenerative case, your solution must traverse the entire string whereas a proper regular expression will stop as soon as a digit is found.

Comment: while this one may not be maximally efficient, it is very readable which can be better for certain situations.

Answer (score 5):

```
if /\d/.match( theStringImChecking ) then
   #yep, there's a number in the string
end
```

Answer (score 4):

```
!s[/\d/].nil?
```

Can be a standalone function -

```
def has_digits?(s)
  return !s[/\d/].nil?
end
```

or ... adding it to the String class makes it even more convenient -

```
class String
  def has_digits?
    return !self[/\d/].nil?
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Rather than use something like "s =~ /\d/", I go for the shorter s[/\d/] which returns nil for a miss (AKA false in a conditional test) or the index of the hit (AKA true in a conditional test). If you need the actual value use s[/(\d)/, 1]

It should all work out the same and is largely a programmer's choice.