# Check string is a valid number or not in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, parameters

I want to check weather variable contains a valid number or not.

I can validate correctly for null and blank but can not validate text as a "Integer"...

I tried:

```
if(params[:paramA].blank? || (params[:paramA].is_a?(Integer)) )
```

I have also tried is_numeric, is_numeric(string), is_number? and other ways...
but did not get success...

Comment: `validates_numericality_of` (for activerecord)

Comment: `
 "".is_a? Numeric
#=> false
`

Comment: Read this article: http://mentalized.net/journal/2011/04/14/ruby_how_to_check_if_a_string_is_numeric/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I saw such patch:

```
class String
  def is_number?
    true if Float(self) rescue false
  end
end

if (params[:paramA].blank? || !params[:paramA].is_number?)
```

Or without the patch:

```
if (params[:paramA].blank? || (false if Float(params[:paramA]) rescue true))
```

It supports `12`, `-12`, `12.12`, `1e-3` and so on.

Comment: thanks for the quick answer... but i got this error... "undefined method `is_number?' for "awe":String" ... (Note: 'awe' -> is my input)

Comment: Why wouldn't he just use regex instead of all this monkey patching?

Comment: and in the detail he says `...contains a valid number or not` 0 and 0 and 1 are valid numbers? Aren't they? :)

Comment: Well, if he meant what you claim then you're right :) Thanks for your patience with telling me ;)

Answer (score 3):

If your parameter is for an ActiveRecord model, then you should probably use `validates_numericality_of`. Otherwise...

You only want integers, right? How about:

```
if (params[:paramA].blank? || params[:paramA] !~ /^[+-]?\d+$/)
```

That is, check whether the parameter consists of an optional `+` or `-`, followed by 1 or more digits, and nothing else.

Comment: checking for the "validates_numericality_of"

Answer (score 1):

If the thing you want to do is this:

```
I want to check weather variable contains a valid number or not.
```

You can get it with `regex`. See it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2224790/how-do-i-check-if-a-string-has-at-least-one-number-in-it-using-ruby)

```
s = 'abc123'

if s =~ /[-.0-9]+/         # Calling String's =~ method.
  puts "The String #{s} has a number in it."
else
  puts "The String #{s} does not have a number in it."
end
```

Answer (score 1):

In rails you can use the `numeric?` method on a `String` or `Integer` or `Float` which does exactly what you need.

```
123.numeric?
# => true
123.45.numeric?
# => true
"123".numeric?
# => true
"123.45".numeric?
# => true
"a1213".numeric?
# => false
```

**UPDATE**

My bad, I had a dirty environment, the above works if mongoid version 3 and above is loaded.

Comment: srry...but it gives an exception when my input is 'asdf'.... exception: "undefined method `numeric?' for "asdf":String

Comment: It gives you an error because his answer is not part of ruby.
Also, the answer you looking for is this http://mentalized.net/journal/2011/04/14/ruby_how_to_check_if_a_string_is_numeric/