# Count the number of elements of array that contain a digit

Tags: arrays, ruby, string, if-statement, each

i am new to Ruby and stuck on this exercice. I have this array including string value and i am looking for the number of value including a figure ?

```
    array = ["@jcunniet","@PaulLampon","@Aziliz31","@ssoumier","@marionsouzeau","@gaellombart","@bendarag","@AurelieLebelle","@julienduffe","@thomaspoupeau","@LilyRossignol","@ClairGuedon","@stephanieauguy","@claw_prolongeau","@_JulieMenard","@LColcomb","@Zlauwereys","@MeLonguet","@DorotheeLN","@NolwennCosson","@ADaboval","@Remibaldy","@bderveaux","@amandechap","@ELODIESOULIE","@nbongarcon","@HeloAb","@Panamorama","@gregplou","@BenoitBerthe","@LauraBruneau89","@Anthony_Lieures","@Sharonwaj","@mcsonkin","@pverduzier","@emiliel3","@Julien_MARION","@SophiFay","@bdelombre","@annalecerf","@AdriaBudry","@DejNikolic","@iJaffre","@CyrusleVirus","@GPardigon","@e_vallerey","@IsabelleSouquet","@AudeDavidRossi","@Yoann_Pa","@CeliaPenavaire","@perraultvincent","@cboulate","@JustineWeyl","@Paulinejacot","@juliechab","@aslechevallier","@phnou","@Seb_Pommier","@Alex_Bensaid","@GuillaumeGaven","@annelaurechouin","@Oliviader","@guerricp","@JMMarchaut","@cyceron","@gregory_raymond","@vhunsinger","@l_peillon","@fannyguinochet","@EAssayag","@KibweAdom","@YvonHerry","@JohanGarciajg","@saidlabidi","@lauranneprov","@LeaDavy","@francois_remy","@CGuicheteau","@FloMaillet","@m_perroud","@oBrunet_TSMF","@MoonVdc","@jc2taille","@NellyMoussu","@VirginK","@b_misa","@FabriceCouste","@barbara_prose","@lelia2m","@brunoaskenazi","@laurenechamp","@ysisbox","@juliengagliardi","@PierreLel","@kdeniau","@_TerraInc","@DominicArpin","@antoinfonteneau","@nanotousch","@jb_roch","@YaniKhezzar","@Anne_Bechet","@NCapart","@SamyBenNaceur","@Joumany","@Julietteraynal","@TGiraudet","@SaraTanit","@HappeFrederic","@antoinellorca","@michelpicot","@Sev_Ryne","@bobdobolino","@murdever","@YGrandmontagne","@Mnyo","@EdKOSCIANSKI","@tnoisette","@jankari","@delbello_rom","@rflechaux","@NadiaSorelli","@IT_Digital","@abarbaux","@PhilippeLeroy","@schaptal","@marionspee","@lisavignoli","@ChloeAeberhardt","@MartineJacot","@JuliaPascualita","@curieusedetout","@sgraveleau","@bif_o","@ElisaPineau","@zinebdryef","@apiquard","@pierrehaski","@StephanieDelmas","@Blandine_Garot","@vergara_i","@evan_lebastard","@SophieVclt","@OlivierLevrault","@alicedorgeval","@LouiseMalnoy","@alix_fx","@pierre_baudis","@LucMagoutier","@AgatheMuller","@SGianninelli","@PaulineBoyer33","@NaomiHalll","@romaindlx","@marionbr","@Burtschy","@JacobEtienne","@as_lizzani","@marie_simon","@LaureDaussy","@FabriceAmedeo","@LoubnaChlaikhy","@PlummerWilliam","@OlivierMarin1","@alaurefremont","@mwesfreid","@ChBaDe","@pmathon","@theobaldmarie","@Lnpagesy","@marclandre","@paoliniesther","@Feertchak","@JBLitzler","@GuillaumeErrard","@quentinperinel","@TristanQM","@mlbo","@constancejamet","@LoraTerrazas","@emiliegeffray","@Mathilde_Sd","@CaroPiquet","@DCanivez","@TIM_7375","@blandinelc","@ivanrioufol","@arthurberdah","@SarahLecoeuvre","@guillaume_gui","@DamienMercereau","@W_Chloe","@Assma_MD","@EugenieBastie","@HiTech_lexpress","@bcondominas","@Laurie_Z_","@jeanfrancgerard","@MathieuPagura","@BGUYF","@AlainPiffaretti","@AudreyKucinskas","@julienhory","@Pierrefalga","@TiphThuillier","@cdaniez","@LigerBaptiste","@D_Peras","@julie_dlb","@Fatiha_Temmouri","@julian2lamancha","@GaetaneDeljurie","@JulianMattei","@M_Vicuna","@DeBruynOlivier","@Nehed_Jendoubi","@antoine_grenapi","@ColonnaGen","@VictoriaGairin","@Clement_Lacombe","@TVigoureux","@MargauxObriot","@solinedelos","@RocheSabine","@dangerkens","@EdouardDutour","@MDondeyne","@DupuisNathalie1","@bouscarel","@Mathieu2jean","@Sophie_T_J","@laurentcalixte","@patrockwilliams","@PascaleKremer","@AlexJaquin","@LauraIsaaz","@cath_robin","@Del_Gautherin","@Isaduriez","@lucietuile","@AugeyBastien","@mcastagnet","@AminaKalache","@mvaudano","@CParrot","@ombelinetips","@_JoinLion","@BarbolosiRose","@ToiBruno1","@FloraClodic","@xjbdx","@AlexiaEy","@Emjy_STARK","@elcoco01","@rabilebon","@pflovens_","@FabriceFrossard","@MorganeSERRES","@MarjolaineKoch","@edgarsnow","@SRNLF","@CChassigneux","@KerinecMoran","@NassiraELM","@NewsRicard","@Sandreene","@Emilezrt","@Pierre_Do","@Micode","@CColumelli","@DavidAbiker","@ClementBergantz","@benjaminrabier","@celinekallmann","@edwyplenel","@C_Barbier","@JJBourdin_RMC","@LaurenceFerrari","@aslapix","@IsaMillet","@MaximeSwitek","@tomjoubert","@jszanchi","@roqueeva","@XavierBiseul","@florencesantrot","@AntoineCrochet","@freeman59","@MaudeML","@philippe_gulpi","@mathieum76","@kiouari","@imanemoustakir","@BenedicteMallet","@Emilie_Brouze","@antoinebarret","@_nicolasbocquet","@remibuhagiar","@CourretB","@AymericRobert","@miraelmartins","@pmaniere","@jesuisraphk","@David_Ingram","@pcelerier","@technomedia","@Geraldinedauver","@ThierryLabro","@Newsdusud","@nrauline","@gbregeras","@SCouasnonBFM","@actualites_nrv","@dimitrimoulins","@oli_aura","@FabieChiche","@Vincent_Raimblt","@ChristophGreuet","@PAlbuchay","@MarrauddesGrot","@vtalmon","@cedric","@olivierfrigara","@Julien_Jay","@LydiaBerroyer","@Shuua","@datisdaz","@Steuph","@ameliecharnay","@Bruno_LesNums","@LelloucheNico","@CciliaDiQuinzio","@Elodie_C","@SylvRolland","@Kocobe","@FL_Debes","@jdupontcalbo","@GarciaVictor_","@NicoRichaud","@RHoueix","@simottel","@DamienLicata","@annabelle_L","@Lea_Lejeune","@axel_deb","@marin_eben","@ptiberry","@MatthieuDelach","@sandrinecassini","@benjaminferran","@ppgarcia75","@NotPatrick","@ivalerio","@FabienneSchmitt","@alexgoude","@JeromeColombain","@manhack","@Capucine_Cousin","@Fsorel","@oliviertesquet","@marjoriepaillon","@ginades","@PierreTran","@DelphineCuny","@reesmarc","@lauratenoudji","@ldupin","@carolinedescham","@Lucile_Quillet","@cgabizon","@Allocab","@epenser","@JAGventeprivee","@frwrds","@Laure__Bourdon","@Xavier75","@maximeverner","@s_jourdain","@LoriHelloc"]


i = 0
array.each do |n|
    if n.include?("1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10")
    then i += 1
    end
puts i
end
```

Comment: You were close to solution here - but instead of looking for 1, 2, or 3 as numbers - you were looking for actual "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10" string to appear as a whole in string value from that array.

Comment: Yes i understand, the value of the array are strings and i am looking for the number of value including a number therefore i need to iterate over the string with .each to increment i every time it finds a number in a string

Comment: I don't understand the goal. `"@Aziliz31"` should count for 2 because of `3` and `1` or zero because `31` is not listed in `"1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10"`? How to count for `"@Aziliz0"`, zero or one? Can you show some examples?

Comment: The aim was to count i += 1 each time an array value is including a figure or a number

Comment: Do you wish to count the number of elements of `array` that contain at least one digit? That would include strings that contain only zeroes. You need to edit your question to clarify your objective (even though you’ve selected an answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
array.grep(/[1-9]/).count
```

Edit: Changed regEx from /[1-10]/ to /[1-9]/

Comment: Alternatives can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2224790/how-do-i-check-if-a-string-has-at-least-one-number-in-it-using-ruby

Comment: I don't see how i can use this from now but let's find out

Comment: This has the weakness that a temporary array is created (by `grep`). It’s more efficient to determine the desired count directly. Note you don’t need the last sentence (“Edit:...”).

Answer (score 0):

Often code that is the direct translation of the question is best: “Count the number of elements of `array` that contain a digit”.

```
array.count { |s| s.match? /\d/ }
```

See [Array#count](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Array.html#method-i-count) and [String#match?](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6/String.html#method-i-match-3F).