# how to check if user input contains a number? in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I don't want to see if user input is an integer value, I just want to see if there's an integer within the user's input (a string).

I was thinking of using include? or contains but neither worked for me.

Comment: Like any number at all? Does `abc123def` count as a "number'?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I check if a string has at least one number in it using Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2224790/how-do-i-check-if-a-string-has-at-least-one-number-in-it-using-ruby)

Comment: "neither worked for me" is not a precise enough error description for us to help you. *What* doesn't work? *How* doesn't it work? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ?

Comment: What is the code you are having trouble with? What trouble do you have with your code? Please, provide a [mre]. Please be aware that [so] is not a code-writing service, you need to show your efforts! https://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/ https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/ https://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/ https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/

Answer (score 3):

Lazy solution:

```
input = gets.chomp
input[/\d+/]
```

You can also check with `match?` on Ruby 2.6+:

```
input.match?(/\d+/)
```